# Authenticate with GitHub using a token

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to authenticate with GitHub using a personal access token. In the help files at GitHub, it states to use the cURL method to authenticate (*[Creating a personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use)*). I have tried this, but I still cannot push to GitHub. Please note, I am trying to push from an unauthenticated server ([Travis CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travis_CI)).

```
cd $HOME
git config --global user.email "emailaddress@yahoo.com"
git config --global user.name "username"

curl -u "username:<MYTOKEN>" https://github.com/username/ol3-1.git
git clone --branch=gh-pages https://github.com/username/ol3-1.git gh-pages

cd gh-pages
mkdir buildtest
cd buildtest
touch asdf.asdf

git add -f .
git commit -m "Travis build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER pushed to gh-pages"
git push -fq origin gh-pages
```

This code causes the errors:

> remote: Anonymous access to scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git denied.

> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git/'"

Comment: As of 2021-Aug-28, github CLI can be used to authenticate (no need to generating PAT, can directly login with password if browser can be opened). Checkout: https://github.com/cli/cli#installation, https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

Comment: For anyone like me: to make git remember your token on the fresh system: run `git config --global credential.helper store`, then simply clone some private repo you have access to. Git cli will ask for username/password. Password is your token. After that git cli remembers the credentials

Answer (score 567, accepted):

Your `curl` command is entirely wrong. You should be using the following

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token <MYTOKEN>' ...
```

That aside, that doesn't authorize your computer to clone the repository if in fact it is private. (Taking a look, however, indicates that it is not.) What you would normally do is the following:

```
git clone https://scuzzlebuzzle:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git --branch=gh-pages gh-pages
```

That will add your credentials to the remote created when cloning the repository. Unfortunately, however, you have no control over how Travis clones your repository, so you have to edit the remote like so.

```
# After cloning
cd gh-pages
git remote set-url origin https://scuzzlebuzzle:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git
```

That will fix your project to use a remote with credentials built in.

> Warning: Tokens have read/write access and should be treated like passwords. If you enter your token into the clone URL when cloning or adding a remote, `Git writes it to your .git/config file in plain text, which is a security risk.`

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help. It worked great. Here is a copy of my changed file: https://github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1/blob/master/util/s.sh. I got it pretty close. For some reason it didn't push to the build1 directory I created, but it still pushed to the build directory so it worked! THANKS!

Comment: Also for some reason my github page editor button now says "Propose File Changes." Maybe I should remove the "git remote rm origin" line?

Comment: I don't know what editor button you're speaking of but removing the original remote is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Was talking about the button on the edit page at the bottom: https://github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1/edit/master/util/s.sh. It still seems to save changes though so doesn't look like a problem. Again, thank you. I added a sigma rocks file in the directory!

Comment: Heh. [Cool.](https://github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1/blob/gh-pages/sigma/sigma.rocks) Glad to help.

Comment: You don't have to rm the remote, you can use set-url instead, as in `git remote set-url origin https://scuzzlebuzzle:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git`

Comment: Insecure approach. Key easily cat'd to logs on error. Use a tightly scoped deploy key instead.

Comment: Notice that you can also clone using the url with only the token like `git clone https://<MYTOKEN>@github.com/scuzzlebuzzle/ol3-1.git`. The Windows client will save the token in the origin remote (that gets added automatically upon cloning), so future commands will work, BUT I discovered that the Linux client won't, except if you also add the username before the token. This answer gave me the idea to try with the username also. Thanks!

Comment: btw: personal access tokens can be created here: https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: Note that a more secure approach is to do `git push https://username:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/username/repo.git ` since that doesn't store the token in plaintext.

Comment: @KartikSoneji - Sure it does... in you bash history. I'm unclear on how this new token based auth could be more secure than private ssh key. Every solution I've seen so far involves exposing the token in some way.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden Sorry, I meant that as someone using Windows cmd, which doesn't store command history once the terminal exits. Also, you can prefix the command with a space to keep it out of your bash history, and you cannot normally read the `~/.bash_history` of other users. Finally, I agree that SSH keys are the most secure, but this is more useful when you need to do a push from a system (like a remote server) without having to setup too many things.

Comment: @KartikSoneji Agreed. I'm just pointing out that GitHub (and the community) should probably be recommending a move to ssh auth, not token auth as a consequence of no password access (i.e. command line git and other manual use cases). We've had deploy keys for remote server automation for a long time now. GitHub communication is very odd on this topic.

Comment: Normal git workflows do not expose passwords or ssh private keys to other users with read access to a repo. The above advice does. It allows anyone with read access to a copy of a local repo, including for example a shared work or school filesystem, to see the user's clear text Personal Access Token. This extends to archived copies as well, such as source tarballs that retain the .git directory.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I was getting a real headache with github's new two factor authentication system...

Comment: the command you are looking for is `git remote set-url origin https://<USERNAME>:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git`

Comment: @Lukas's comment worked for me. `scuzzlebuzzle` in the answer is your github username, which will be in the URL for the repository. So, get the URL (in the github settings for the repository), and prefix it with <USERNAME> (from the URL) and <MYTOKEN>, ie `<USERNAME>:<MYTOKEN>@`, in `git remote set-url origin `

Comment: How does one update the token in local with the new generated token if we have cloned using old access token `git clone https://username:personalaccesstoken@github.com/repo`?

Comment: @StephenHosking When using a GitHub personal access token, the username is not required by GitHub. I could do `git push https://scuzzlebuzzle:<MYTOKEN>@github.com/<MYUSERNAME>/<MYREPO>.git` and it will push as my user account.

Comment: Im using this approach but it only works if I invoke the .sh locally. If I want to invoke it remotely (Using ssh) from a different machine (Windows, through a .bat that passes the token as a parameter to the .sh) it fails the authentication

Answer (score 376):

First, you need to create a personal access token (PAT). This is described here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Laughably, the article tells you how to create it, but gives absolutely no clue what to do with it. After about an hour of trawling documentation and Stack Overflow, I finally found the answer:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user-or-organisation/myrepo.git
Username: <my-username>
Password: <my-personal-access-token>
```

I was actually forced to enable [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) by company policy while I was working remotely and still had local changes, so in fact it was not `clone` I needed, but `push`. I read in lots of places that I needed to delete and recreate the remote, but in fact my normal `push` command worked exactly the same as the `clone` above, and the remote did not change:

```
$ git push https://github.com/user-or-organisation/myrepo.git
Username: <my-username>
Password: <my-personal-access-token>
```

<sub>(@YMHuang put me on the right track with the documentation link.)</sub>

Comment: I tried several times this approach, but I am facing the same issue. I generated the PTA and then tried to authenticate after push command execution, putting my username and my token. It still tells me that credentials are wrong. What am I missing in these steps?

Comment: So where are we expected to get the token from in order to enter it wherever it's needed? Are we seriously expected to copy it into a file everywhere and then paste it into authentication prompts whenever we need to use Git. If so that's the shitest workflow I've ever heard of but the Git docs don't seem to have any other suggestions.

Comment: _"Beginning August 13, 2021, we will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com."_ This should be interesting.

Comment: I didn't have to `git push url`. Just git push was good enough, along with username, and password.

Comment: Why don't they explain what to do with the token after creating it?!

Comment: After doing `git push https://github.com/user-or-organisation/myrepo.git` ; `git` still asks for username and password

Comment: All the people here who are rightly complaining about GitHub's failure to indicate how to use the token have visitied https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-token-on-the-command-line and given feedback at the bottom of the page, right?

Comment: Yes thank you! They need to update their docs. This would have saved me an hour of my time.

Comment: In short, basically instead of typing in your password, you should just type in the access token. This is also for the git push.

Comment: Nobody knows their PAT from he top of their head. So they "force" us to put the PAT into the git config for the remote url where anyone can access it. I don't understand this decision from GitHub.

Comment: Agreed - they explain how to generate the token, but provide no help in how to use <TOKEN>. Since M$ bought Github it's gone to the dogs.

Comment: @T3rm1 The tokens are scoped and can be easily managed (revoked) from the UI. You don't have to worry about your github credentials which will remain secret. Make sure to scope the tokens wisely. In that, they are a very usable packaged version of ssh keys.

Comment: This also worked for me. GIT BASH was returning a username and password prompt box. Initially I thought my network PW was to be used in the 2nd PW field. This did not authenticate (I am using VS Online as a GIT repos BTW). I instead created a personnel access token in VS online in the relevant repos and used that in the PW field. Worked 1st time. Thanks.

Answer (score 202):

## Generating a token

Generate a token using the instructions from *[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)*.
(GitHub profile -> Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal access tokens)

## Actually using the token

- If you already have the repository cloned locally

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@github.com/[REPO-OWNER]/[REPO-NAME]
git push
```

- If you are cloning a new repository

```
git clone https://[TOKEN]@github.com/[REPO-OWNER]/[REPO-NAME]
```

---

(Replace the square brackets and what's between them with your corresponding details. The part after the the `@` is the same as the repository url without https://)

Comment: First I used this one `git remote set-url origin https://[TOKEN]@git.mycompany.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git` , it just worked for git pull, but when I ran command git push, git again prompt for username. Its annoying to put token in password field again and again, so above mentioned commands in same order worked for me.

Comment: To grantee that all these steps will work while pushing to Github, you need to select the scopes, or permissions, you'd like to grant this token to access your repositories from the command line.

Comment: If you try this for an organization, (and you're stupid like me), be aware that [USER] means your organization's user name and not your personal user name.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to `remove` origin and then add. It will be overwritten so just the `add` is sufficient

Comment: Short & Simple for all users :)

Comment: Worked great to update an expired token on an existing local repo.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, so before my account was protected by a private key using ssh, now it's unprotected. this bothers me so much...

Comment: Oh, so one goes and put a private information in the clear, in an URL, for every sniffer and router to see. And bash history. nice.

Comment: so the person i grant the access to (key) cannot recieve it in the format of link ? he has to access it via terminal ?

Comment: This actually works. I tried using the `git config --global credential.helper wincred` but with not luck. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 134):

This worked for me *using ssh*:

*Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Generate new token*.

```
git remote set-url origin https://[APPLICATION]:[NEW TOKEN]@github.com/[ORGANISATION]/[REPO].git
```

Comment: This also works for personal access tokens using this format: `git remote add origin https://[USERNAME]:[NEW TOKEN]@github.com/[USERNAME]/[REPO].git`

Comment: I had to do `git remote add origin https://[USERNAME]:[TOKEN]@git.mycompany.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git`

Comment: Isn't this a bad idea? Won't the token get cached in the console history?

Comment: Also worked for me git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@git.mycompany.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git

Comment: @TheRealChx101You can use something like `git remote set-url origin https://[TOKEN]@git.mycompany.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git> /dev/null 2>&1` to avoid logging of insecure git output. Store the token in a variable to avoid having it in the log. But it needs to be stored somewhere. To secure further you can store it encrypted. This approach is for example supported by Travis CI.

Comment: @ThomasChafiol and TheRealChx101 When your token expires or if eg, windows password updates your company-wide enterprise authentication this would be the correct approach or rather a combination of your two answers `git remote set-url origin https://[TOKEN]@git.mycompany.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git`

Comment: This is the best answer can you share a source to this information besides is there any automated way to update token for example `git update-token my-secret-token`using `set-url` with manually edited url is error prone

Comment: You can regenerate personal access token anytime if you forgot. It will be like string ghp_nGCyfjofU5LVCTvUUkVsjP7Yd9qkya1HxCo8. Now on github it is your password to push your project on github.

Answer (score 94):

### Step 1: Get the access token

Go to this link: **https://github.com/settings/tokens**. And generate the token there.

**Or** from you Github account, Go to:
**Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access Tokens**

### Step 2: Use the token

```sh
git push

Username: <your username>
Password: <the access token>
```

Comment: For anyone wanting things to work like they do for Omar, I could not get it to work unless i first did 
`$ git config credential.helper store`. Note: The credentials will be saved unencrypted on a file inside your home directory, therefore use it with discretion.
[A better explanation can be found here](http://gmacario.github.io/2017/08/08/cmdline-git-with-github-2fa.html)

Comment: @Steinarr the link is not valid.

Comment: @Timo [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201216132223/http://gmacario.github.io/2017/08/08/cmdline-git-with-github-2fa.html) is a wayback machine link to the site as it was

Comment: More simple than this is impossible. Thanks!

Comment: This worked beautifully!

Answer (score 90):

Automation / Git automation with OAuth tokens

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
  Username: your_token
  Password:
```

It also works in the `git push` command.

Reference: 
https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/

Comment: The key is to set git so that you do not need to be prompted at all times for your token, as described here - https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Other answers to this question will end up writing your token in plaintext to .git/config which could be considered a security risk.

Comment: This is the safest approach so far.

Answer (score 42):

### To avoid handing over "the keys to the castle"...

Note that sigmavirus24's response requires you to give Travis a token with fairly wide permissions -- since GitHub only offers tokens with wide scopes like "write all my public repos" or "write all my private repos".

If you want to tighten down access (with a bit more work!) you can use GitHub deployment keys combined with Travis encrypted yaml fields.

Here's **a sketch** of how the technique works...

First generate an RSA deploy key (via `ssh-keygen`) called `my_key` and add it as a deploy key in your github repo settings.

Then...

```
$ password=`openssl rand -hex 32`
$ cat my_key | openssl aes-256-cbc -k "$password" -a  > my_key.enc
$ travis encrypt --add password=$password -r my-github-user/my-repo
```

Then use the `$password` file to decrypt your deploy key at integration-time, by adding to your yaml file:

```
before_script: 
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -k "$password" -d -a -in my_key.enc -out my_deploy_key
  - echo -e "Host github.com\n  IdentityFile /path/to/my_deploy_key" > ~/.ssh/config
  - echo "github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Note: the last line pre-populates github's RSA key, which avoids the need for manually accepting at the time of a connection.

Answer (score 40):

For macOS, if you are not prompted with a username and password request, it means your password is stored in Keychain Access. Every time you try to clone or push it will try to use your old password.

Follow these three steps to solve this:

1. Generate a [PAT](https://microclimate.dev/creatingpat) (personal access token) - [LINK](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. Open KeyChain Access (Via spotlight search) → search GitHub → click GitHub → change and save with your new PAT [link](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain)
3. Try to push or clone again. Now you have stored the PAT instead of your password.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you!

Comment: Seriously, this. I would've never figured this one out, thank you so much!

Comment: This should be in the Github FAQ written exactly as this. If it already is I was not able to find it. Thanks for making this ridiculously clear.

Comment: The only answer which helps with updating the token rather than setting a new one. Should be higher ranked.

Answer (score 40):

You can easily change your remote Authentication, first:

Remove your current origin:

```
git remote remove origin
```

And then:

```
git remote add origin https://<TOKEN>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git
```

You can find how to generate your Authentication Token [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: this is a super answer, the above ones didn't work

Comment: Didn't work for me!

Comment: confirm this one worked!

Comment: this is my goto approach now, its so weird github made this decision.

Answer (score 39):

Normally I do like this:

```
 git push https://$(git_token)@github.com/user_name/repo_name.git
```

The *git_token* is reading from variable *config* in [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server).

You can read my full blog post [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2020/03/05/sync-repository-change-from-azure-devops-to-github/).

Comment: this can invoke: remote: No anonymous write access.

Comment: I Actually had to remove the dollar sign in order to make it work. Thus the template should actually look like this:                                                                                                  git push https://(git_token)@github.com/user_name/repo_name.git

Answer (score 27):

I'm on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) and I kept getting the message that soon I wouldn't be able to log in from console.  I was terribly confused.

Finally, I got to the URL below which will work.  But you need to know how to create a [PAT](https://microclimate.dev/creatingpat) (personal access token) which you are going to have to keep in a file on your computer.

Here's what the final URL will look like:

```
git push https://1234567890123456789012345678901234567890@github.com/user-name/repo.git
```

**long PAT (personal access token)** value -- The entire long value between the // and the @ sign in the URL is your PAT.

**user-name** will be your exact username

**repo.git** will be your exact repository name

Also you will be able to use it this way too:

When you do a

`git push`

**1.** You'll be prompted for a username and password

**2.** Just submit your username as normal

**3.** Now submit your PAT as your password and it will work.

You need to generate a PAT following the steps at: *[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)*

That will give you the PAT value that you will place in your URL.

When you create the PAT make sure you choose the following options so it has the ability to allow you to manage your repositories.

[image: PAT settings]

**Save Your PAT Or Lose It**

Once you have your PAT, you're going to need to save it in a file locally so you can use it again.  If you don't save it somewhere there is no way to ever see it again and you'll be forced to create a new PAT.

Now you're going to need at the very least:

1. a way to display it in your console so you can see it again.
2. or, a way to copy it to your clipboard automatically.

**For 1, just use**:

```
cat ~/files/myPatFile.txt
```

Where the path is a real path to the location and file where you stored your PAT value.

**For 2**

```
xclip -selection clipboard < ~/files/myPatFile.txt
```

That'll copy the contents of the file to the clipboard so you can use your PAT more easily.

FYI - if you don't have xclip do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

It downloads and installs xclip. If you don't have `apt-get`, you might need to use another installer (like [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software))).

Comment: `git config credential.helper cache` could be used to save password for a default of 15 mins. Also `git config credential.helper store` can be used to permanently store the password for that repo (less "secure"). More info [here](http://gmacario.github.io/2017/08/08/cmdline-git-with-github-2fa.html)

Answer (score 25):

I previously used passwords to access my private repositories using Git CLI and had saved my credentials with `git config --global credential.helper store`.

As support for passwords has been dropped today, I couldn't manage to update my credentials with the token using the `git config` commands suggested.

If anyone else has this problem on Linux, you can manually update the `~/.git-credentials` file, e.g.

```sh
nano ~/.git-credentials
```

Enter your token between the `:` and `@` symbols. (To save and close the file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>).

You might have to also run the following command after updating your token in the credentials file (see @guhur's comment):

```sh
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Note that by using Git's credential helper, anyone who has access to your home directory can see your token.

Comment: Thanks, this was literally the only thing that worked for me after spending 3 hours on this.  Only I deleted ~/.git-credentials, and then used git config credential.helper store

Comment: Thanks. So the steps are: 1) create a personal token from Github, 2) put :<your-personal-token>@ in ~/.git-credentials, 3) run `git config --global credential.helper store`

Comment: @guhur not sure step 3 is even needed. The next time authentication is required, git directly reads from the credentials file (at least as far as I recall)

Comment: I actually needed it

Comment: Thanks!! This was what I really needed :)

Comment: What is *"the token sugin"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68776295/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for pointing this out; that was just a typo. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I was able to authenticate VSC via PAT but following previous steps, in cli keeing getting "fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: token"

Comment: @CarmineTambascia Haven't worked with VSC, but it's possible it uses its own git binary. A similar issue has been brought here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61383299/7089726, maybe that can help you solve the issue with git cli.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear, with VSC the authentication via PAT is working fine. The issue I am facing is via Command line(ubuntu)

Comment: @Carmine no idea what VSC PAT is. When using git cli, make sure git credentials file doesn't have an excess empty line (as suggested in the answer I shared). Also see this answer if you are running a version older than 2.27 (`git --version`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704149/7089726. It suggests this could be due to a bug with URL parsing in an older version.

Comment: @undefined PAT stay for Personal Access Token, as discussed in this question. It is the new way to authorizing access to github. Nevertheless thank you for the link, I will have a look

Answer (score 15):

I had to add `oauth` or `oauth2` as username to successfully authenticate:

```
https://oauth:<TOKEN>@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: It seems the username doesn't matter at all. I tried "foobar" and it still worked. But not prefixing with "<ANYTHING>:" leads to the following error:

```fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address```

Comment: @siwyd hmm... interesting, so it should work like this as well `https://:<TOKEN>@github.com/user/repo.git`

Answer (score 14):

The only answer that helped me in a VS Code environment and a private GitHub.

- First => generate the token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens.
- Second => do a "cd" to the right place in your VS Code terminal.
- Third => follow as this example:

`git clone https://[MY_USER_NAME]:[GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]@github.com/davidsonlima/davidson-myrepo.git` without square brackets

Comment: recipient can acess repository only via terminal ? I wanted to share a link (like available only via link feature)

Answer (score 13):

Since I am using macOS, I can answer this for macOS specifically.
We can use this for Windows also. It works!!
In your GitHub account, click on the top right avatar and go to settings [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RY5s.).

Click on *Settings*:

[image: settings]

Click on *Developer settings*:

[image: Developer settings]

Click on *Personal Access Tokens*:

[image: Personal Access Tokens]

[image: Personal Access Tokens (Details)]

And then click on *Generate new token*:

[image: generate new token]

Give a name to your access token and check on the first option.

Scroll down and click on generate token

Now, when you push the repo, use the following syntax:

```
git remote add origin https:<access__token>://@github.com/<username>/<repo__name>.git

git push https://<access__token>@github.com/<username>/<repo__name>.git
```

In my opinion, you can use the second option, while pushing the repo provide access token and you're good to go.

Comment: last following example was helpful. this works for me.

Answer (score 12):

The following steps works for me:

1. `git remote remove origin`
2. `git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@[REPO LINK]`

###### For example, my repo name is: https://github.com/username/codf.git.

The command will be:

`git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@github.com/username/codf.git`

3. `git push origin branchName`

Answer (score 10):

1. ```
   git remote remove origin
   ```
2. ```
   git remote add origin https://{accesstoken}:{accesstoken}@gitlab.com/{username}/{repo}.git
   ```
3. ```
   git push https://{youraccesstoken}@github.com/{username}/{repo}.git
   ```

This works for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using GitHub Enterprise and cloning the repository or pushing gives you a 403 error instead of prompting for a username/token, you can use this:

1. Delete the repository
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder you want the repository in
3. Type:

   ```
   git clone https://[USERNAME]:[TOKEN]@[GIT_ENTERPRISE_DOMAIN]/[ORGANIZATION]/[REPO].git
   ```

Comment: Normal git workflows do not expose passwords or ssh private keys to other users with read access to a repo. The above advice does. It allows anyone with read access to a copy of a local repo, including for example a shared work or school filesystem, to see the user's clear text Personal Access Token. This extends to archived copies as well, such as source tarballs that retain the .git directory.

Comment: The only answer that helped me in a VS Code environment and a private GitHub. First generate the token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens. Second do a "cd" to the right place in your computer. Third follow as example: 
```git clone https://davidsonlima:qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm@github.com/davidsonlima/davidson-myrepo.git```

Answer (score 7):

I suffered with this problems but found a solution:

```
git push https://github.com/<username>/<project_name>
and
username: paste your personnal access token
password: paste your personnal access token
```

Comment: Are you sure you use your personal access token for both you username _and_ your password, and not just for your password?

Comment: Regardless, this is suspiciously similar to [@Echelon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39530966/3025856) from five years ago, but with far less detail.

Comment: I used my personnal access token for the username and password.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: it worked for me . thanks that is the best and quickest solution

Comment: It worked for me too, TBH this is either a bug or expected, can't find any documentation for this piece, the official documentation suggests (rather obviously) providing user name for username

Answer (score 6):

**For Windows:**

1. Open Credential Manager - Windows Credentials
2. Find the entry of `git:https://github.com`, edit it
3. replace your former password with the PAT access token
4. Solved

Answer (score 4):

Having struggled with this issue for pretty much a full day, hard coding in the ORG/REPO section into our build script getting the dreaded 'remote not found' error, eventually I found a working solution by using `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG`.

Switching this in for the hardcoded attributes worked immediately.

```sh
git remote set-url origin https://[ORG]:${TOKEN}@github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those coming from [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab), what's worked for me:

#### Prerequisite:

Create a token:

- 1. Select the necessary permissions
- 2. Select expiration date
- 3. Generate by pressing `create personal access token`
- #### Save the token!

#### Step 1.

Add a remote:

`git remote add origin https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@gitlab.com/path/to/project.git`

#### Step 2.

Pull once:

`https://<access-token-name>:<access-token>@gitlab.com/path/to/project.git`

**Now you are able to read/write to/from the repository**

Answer (score 4):

Lately github is not allowing commits directly from cmd using our username and password. For that we need to generate the accesss token as elaborated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221643).

And then use the same access token as username and password in the command prompt for git commands `git push`, `git pull` etc. For example

```
git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': lhq_4npmklMYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL8SxHxU
Password for 'https://lhq_4npmklMYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXL8SxHxU@github.com':<give same access token here as password too>
```

And you start to see the code logs as:

```
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 6.33 KiB | 539.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxx-xxxxx-repo.git
123456..1233456  master -> master
```

Hope this helps someone. Happy Coding !!! :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Was just curious to know whether we could save our token somewhere so that we do not have to copy and paste it every time? Somewhere like in the git config? I want to run it in my Windows WSL, if that is any help.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using [github deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) which narrow access to a single github repo as well as making write permission optional.

Github deploy keys use a user generated ssh key using `ssh-keygen` which creates a private key file and a public key files.

Suppose the key name given `ssh-keygen` is `key-test`, and the private and public files live in `~/.ssh/key-test` and `~/.ssh/key-test.pub` respectively.

Suppose the github project name is `keytest`.

To add a deploy key to project via the github project web page, got `settings/deploy keys` and click `add`.  Paste the contents of the public key file `~/.ssh/key-test.pub` into the target box and confirm.

Modify the contents of your `~/.ssh/config` file to include the following:

```
Host gh-keytest
        Hostname github.com
        IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/key-test
```

*Note: `gh-keytest` is an arbitrary alias.*

Now you can push using

```
git push git@gh-keytest:<githubaccountname>/keytest.git
```

To do it using only push

```
git remote remove origin  # in case origin is already set
git remote add origin git@gh-keytest:<githubaccountname>/testscope.git
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

*Note: Replace `main` with the correct intended branch name.*

Thereafter

```
git push
```

is sufficient.

Comment: This only works if your Organization in GitHub does not require SAML SSO. If they do, you have to use a Token as demonstrated in other answers. The TO did not specify whether that is the case for them, but it may be relevant to others who come here for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac users:

1. Open *Keychain Access* and find GitHub
2. Right-click in GitHub
3. Click delete
4. Open the terminal and try to clone a private project
5. Add the required values 
   Username: $your GitHub username 
   Password: $paste token here 
   And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Voilà - the token has been added.

Answer (score 3):

To update your remote repo with a new access token

```
git remote set-url origin https://{{your_username}}:{{your_new_token}}@github.com/{{repo_path}}.git
```

Comment: This is for a repo, how would you grant access across all repos at once?

Answer (score 2):

The password that you use to log in to github.com portal does not work in the [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) CLI/shell. You should copy the PAT token from URL *https://github.com/settings/tokens* by generating a new token and paste that string in CLI as the password.

Answer (score 1):

By having struggling so many hours  on applying **GitHub token** finally it works as below:

> `$ cf_export GITHUB_TOKEN=$(codefresh get context github --decrypt -o
>   yaml | yq -y .spec.data.auth.password)`

- code follows [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/codefresh-yaml/steps/git-clone/#reuse-a-git-token-from-codefresh-integrations) guidance on cloning a repo using token (freestyle}
- test carried: **sed** `%d%H%M` on match word `'-123456-whatever'`
- **push back** to the repo (which is **private repo**)
- triggered by [DockerHub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/) **webhooks**

Following is the complete code:

```
version: '1.0'
steps:
  get_git_token:
    title: Reading Github token
    image: codefresh/cli
    commands:
      - cf_export GITHUB_TOKEN=$(codefresh get context github --decrypt -o yaml | yq -y .spec.data.auth.password)
  main_clone:
    title: Updating the repo
    image: alpine/git:latest
    commands:
      - git clone https://chetabahana:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/chetabahana/compose.git
      - cd compose && git remote rm origin
      - git config --global user.name "chetabahana"
      - git config --global user.email "chetabahana@gmail.com"
      - git remote add origin https://chetabahana:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/chetabahana/compose.git
      - sed -i "s/-[0-9]\{1,\}-\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)'/-`date +%d%H%M`-whatever'/g" cloudbuild.yaml
      - git status && git add . && git commit -m "fresh commit" && git push -u origin master
```

Output...

```
On branch master 
Changes not staged for commit: 
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed) 
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory) 

modified:   cloudbuild.yaml 

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a") 
[master dbab20f] fresh commit 
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-) 
Enumerating objects: 5, done. 
Counting objects:  20% (1/5) ...  Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads 
Compressing objects:  33% (1/3) ... Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 283 bytes | 283.00 KiB/s, done. 
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0) 
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/2)  ...   (2/2), completed with 2 local objects. 
To https://github.com/chetabahana/compose.git 
   bbb6d2f..dbab20f  master -> master 
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'. 
Reading environment variable exporting file contents. 
Successfully ran freestyle step: Cloning the repo
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone your project -> git clone https://token@github.com//project.git
2. In Project folder -> git config --global credential.helper cache

and work

Answer (score 1):

Select vcs → push tab from [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio). A popup would be displayed with username and password. Enter your username and instead of a password, enter the token number. It will get pushed to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

After generating access token from Developer setting, run these commands,
`git push origin [branch] Username for 'https://github.com': [accessToken] Password for 'https://[accessToken]@github.com':[accessToken]`