# GitHub Actions push changes to remote/origin on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-push, github-actions

I want to automate my build process using GitHub Actions, this process has the following steps:

1. checkout
2. build
3. pack
4. tag
5. increment version
6. commit changes
7. push tags and new commits
8. push package to a repo

I created this main.yml for GitHub Actions:

```
name: Build

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: build

jobs:
  build:
    name: Run build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          ref: 'master'
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # checkout master, 'cause of detached head
      - name: Checkout master
        run: git checkout master

      # run the build script
      - name: Build
        if: success()
        run: .\build\build.ps1

      # pack everything
      - name: Pack
        if: success()
        run: .\build\pack.ps1

      # tag this version
      - name: Tag
        if: success()
        run: .\build\tag.ps1

      # increment version
      - name: Increment Version
        if: success()
        run: .\build\increment-version.ps1

      # Commit changes
      - name: Add & Commit
        if: success()
        run: |
          git config user.email actions@github.com
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git commit -a -m "Automated build" --author="GitHub Actions<actions@github.com>"

      # todo: push changes to remote/origin
      - name: Git Push
        if: success()
        run: git push

      # Push package to a repo
      - name: Push Package
        if: success()
        run: .\build\push-package.ps1
```

I tried to use actions provided by the marketplace, but sadly I have to build this application on a windows machine.
Most of the acions exit with the following error message: `##[error]Container action is only supported on Linux`.
The other doesn't work as well, that's why I tried to use the `run` option.

Unfortunately pushing using this way does work neither. I get this output:

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
```

(I have to cancle the task manually.)

I think I have to provide the `{{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` to the push command, but I only find a way to use a basic auth, but all guides (general guides) I have found using this token as bearer token.

How do I push changes back to origin/remote in a GitHub Actions on windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authenticate with GitHub using a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token)

Comment: I already found this question, but sadly it didn't worked with that token (don't know if it was my fault...), but I already found a solution, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567187/5663348. But thanks for effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GitHub Push by ad-m](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-push) fixed my issue. I'm pretty sure that I already tested this action.