# Git push from jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I want to push my code using jenkins pipeline, so is there any way to use `git push` with **HTTPS** from jenkins?

Can we use GitHub personal token for git push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve this goal. I use `sh` steps to run git commands.

After staging and committing the changes locally, the push command will look like

```
def repoUrlWithAuth = "https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git"
def sourceBranch = "<branch-to-push-to>"

git push --repo=${repoUrlWithAuth} --set-upstream ${repoUrlWithAuth} ${sourceBranch}
```

If the initial cloning is done using `https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git`, then the credentials will remain on the git config and you don't need to include `--repo=${repoUrlWithAuth}`.

If the initial cloning has the correct local-remote branch mapping, then you don't need to include `--set-upstream ${repoUrlWithAuth} ${sourceBranch}`

There is [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936804/4022937) that might be of help to figure this out.

Comment: In my case, I used github app credentials to checkout, in the pipeline, I wanted to push at some point. I had to wrap with credentials and then `git remote remove origin` followed by `git remote add origin ${repUrlWithAuth}` and then I could run `git push origin branch`.