# Clarification: How to add the customize package inside my app in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have changed a `react-native` package src component as per my requirement. **How can I add that in my app?**

(i.e) I have added react-native-floating-action and changed some styles in `FloatingActionItem.js` and `FloatingAction.js` file. How can I add the changes inside in my app.

**Because If I remove the node module all the changes are gone after installing it again.**

Comment: Just keep copy of your current copy safe, remove currently installed one. npm/yarn install <path to your current change>

Comment: As per your suggestion, I think i need to make a copy inside any one of my project folder and then need to remove the node_modules and then need to add that path <component/react-native-floating-action> and then yarn install. Then all the changes in that package will reflect for me.

Comment: Is this option is a good practise?

Answer (score 6):

In your case, once you have modified npm package once you have to reinstall all packages and your changes are not be saved because you are installing dependency from GitHub repository. So anyway you have two options to edit npm package and save it.

1. Copy code from the original repository and make your own component inside your re-usable components folder. ( Before copy whole code read the license of selected package )
2. Simply you can fork the original repository to your github account and after that you can make changes to forked repository.

Personally I choose Second (2) option instead of First one

#### **STEPS**

- Fork from the original repository[image]
- After that make clone of this forked repo to your machine and change whatever you need (Here styles).
- After changing push the changes and commit into your forked repo
- After that you need to remove old original package from your dependency

> npm uninstall --save react-native-floating-action

- After that install forked repo by this command

> npm install git+https://git@github.com/myRepo/angular-translate.git

- Instead of **https://git@github.com/myRepo/angular-translate.git** add your forked project URL here

Comment: How to delete a forked package

Comment: `npm uninstall --save git+https://git@github.com/myRepo/angular-translate.git`

Comment: While pushing the changes I got permission denied error

Comment: You need to push with your personal access token. If you have not generate token, then  you need to generate and add it to your github

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Comment: Use your access token as password -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token

Comment: Did you have any other ways? Because [2] is a good approach. But the personal git URL are not accepted while moving the app to production

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom script using JavaScript which capable of replace, delete and add lines.

NPM automaticly execute `postinstall` after `npm install` command. You need to put your custom script in postinstall within package.json. For an example:

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "my_package",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "fix:issue": "node ./scripts/issue.js",
      "postinstall": "npm run fix:issue"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep your copy on root project folder or anywhere you prefer.
2. `yarn remove <current package name in package.json>`.
3. If this is native library, run `pod install` again for iOS.
4. `yarn add file:/path-to-local-edited-package-folder`
5. Rest of the steps will work same (pod install, etc)

Another approach as you mentioned (I don't suggest it as native libraries might not be removed completely)

1. Remove package from package.json.
2. On package.json file `"library name same as current": "./<path to your folder>"` or any other location.
3. yarn install

Comment: In [1] I need to make the entire copy of that package in my root folder?

Comment: yes the entire folder of that exact package. The root folder name

Comment: Okay, But this is a good approach or not? (i.e) this folder has the all changes and all files from that package. But I have only simple changes in two files alone