# Getting 403 error when trying to push to Git repo

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am getting an error when trying to push changes to Git repo https://github.com/covid19india/covid19india-react.git

I am using Tortoise Git on Windows 7 and using https. I was able to clone the repo using the same user.

Where might the issue be ?

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" refactor_switch_route
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
An error occurred while sending the request.
remote: Permission to covid19india/covid19india-react.git denied to myusername.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/covid19india/covid19india-react.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (14258 ms @ 17-05-2020 17:37:03)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be that you are forbidden to access that repo or you don't have the required access or authentication. Maybe wrong authentication.

Check this out
https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/version-control-systems1/403-forbidden-error-message-when-you-try-to-push-to-a-github-repository

Comment: Awesome..thanks ...that worked...i.e. doing git remote set-url origin "https://username@github.com/username/covid19india-react.git" worked...But still not sure why this was not set automatically when I had cloned the repo....and why I needed to do this explicitly

Comment: Well I also had the same doubt once but you know if you are doing a project in a team and there are many branches of the repo and then you wanna push to a specific repo then this will be really helpful. There are many advantages for this try contributing to a open source repo and you'll learn much more.

Comment: This worked. I think i used the correct url while cloning but it changed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to push to a specific branch of one of my repositories in which I work solo. I tried doing as suggested but it didn't work... What worked for me was adding the repository to Github Desktop and pushing it from there. I know it is not a *solution* but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to run `$ git push origin main` I ran into this problem today and it appears that Github no longer allows you to use your password from terminal. You have to use a Personal Access Token (PAN) or `2 Factor Authentication`.

1- Here are some very simple directions with pictures to [setup a PAN](https://webkul.com/blog/github-push-with-two-factor-authentication/). If for some reason the link doesn't work you can follow the [directions directly from Github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

2- After you create you `PAN`, if you're using a Mac follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192702/4833705) to add your PAN to Keychain. It **100% works**.

After the above 2 simple steps `$ git push origin main` works as normal