# What's the correct way to pass token with git clone using PyPi?

Tags: python, git, pypi

I am using PyPi to clone a github repository, however it a private repo. So I also need to authorise it with my token. I am unable to find any example of how to pass token with the clone request.

```
import git
git.Git('/local/file/path').clone('git@github.com:sample-repo.git', token=(mytoken))
```

This gives an error

`"GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(129)" 
cmdline: git clone --token=mytoken git@github.com:sample-repo.git
stderr: 'error: unknown option token=mytoken'`

It works fine without the token when I try to clone a public repository. So the only issue here is how to pass the token to the above request. Is that possible or is there any other way to authorise git clone in a python script? My objective here is to automate a process to clone a github repository, generate some files using some API calls, add and commit those files to the repository, all within the same python script.

Comment: To use GitHub access tokens, you *must* use https URLs rather than ssh ones. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18935539/1256452 for details.

Comment: The token is meant to be used with GitHub's REST API, not `git` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It worked with the https url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to clone my repository using the https url instead of the ssh url and it worked without the need for token.

```
import git
git.Git('/local/file/path').clone('https://github.com/sample-repo')
```