# How to correctly use GitHub's authentication token?

Tags: authentication, github

When I pushed to my repository using the bash terminal, GitHub sent me an email:

> [GitHub] Deprecation Notice
> Hi,
>
> You recently used a password to access the repository at 
> with git using git/.
>
> Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will
> soon no longer work. Visit
> https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.
>
> Thanks, The GitHub Team

So I tried figuring out how to use the auth token, but [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token), [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow) and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) page didn't really help.

Once I generate a token that looks like this, `ff35995a9624470a855520c573972d2f1812843`, I understand that I'm supposed to be able to do a `git push --all`, then type my username and enter the token to be able to authenticate.
But this would mean that I need to store this token in plain text or in some password manager. That just seems wrong. Or is my understanding of this whole process flawed?

How do I securely use this token instead of a password? I remember [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) had something that I think was a provision for storing such a token, but how would one do it via the Linux terminal securely?

Comment: I'm really confused about this issue, because I successfully used ssh -T and connected and on Ubuntu 20.04 it tells me that " You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."  But that's how the documents tell me how to connect.  If I attempt to sign in with a username and password it warns me that this won't be allowed in the future.  Is console access via git going to be gone from github?

Comment: I finally figured out the exact steps how to move forward with this using a PAT and wrote it up at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token/65831761#65831761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a reply from the [GitHub community](https://github.community/t/how-to-correctly-use-githubs-authentication-token/151299):
Using a password manager would be the preferred solution. You could look into git-credential-cache so you don’t have to enter the token (from the password manager) for each and every push. Using [SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) with an encrypted key and ssh-agent has a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, your password is replaced by a "personal access token", which is just another sort of password. Instructions for how to generate it are [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token). It's completely random so it is impossible to remember.  Cool. Save it in place of your password in a password manager so you can use it when necessary, or there are other solutions such as caching.

See the bottom of [this help page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-token-on-the-command-line) you will see it is used in exactly the same way as a password along with your original username. Also [you might need to switch your repository from ssh to html](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https).

More stackoverflow answers are here [Authenticate with GitHub using a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token/65831761#65831761)

Comment: Please give a bit more detailed instructions here. the links can become 404 over time, but then your basic instructions will remain here forever.