# Could not resolve host: @github.com with pipenv

Tags: python, github, pipenv, pipenv-install

Hello I am trying to install a python package with pipenv, the package is in a private repository and I am using access token in order to download it.

The problem is that when I execute pipenv I got the following error:

> Could not resolve host: @github.com

The GitHub URL is https://token@github.com/user/repo, and when I put it into the browser I can get access to it.

The GitHub token has the following permissions:

[image]

Any idea about why cannot download install with pipenv?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I used the following examples:

```
pipenv install -e "git://token@github.com/user/repo#egg=package"
```

> WARNING: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
pipenv install -e "git+http://token@github.com/user/repo#egg=package"

pipenv install -e "git+https://token@github.com/user/repo#egg=package"
```

> Could not resolve host: @github.com

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual `pipenv` command you used? Also, does it work if you remove the `https://` part?

Comment: updated, with the examples and responses

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository?rq=1? and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token?

Comment: I did, but the problem is that pipenv doesn't recognize the token, I could clone separately the repo with the same url+token, but pipenv return that error and I try to get access to a file into release I got 404 error, but I copy and paste the URL in the browser I can download the whl file.

Comment: I found a couple of issues in the pipenv repo ([#313](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/313) and [#1393](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1393)) that may be of assistance, in addition to using `curl` to authenticate as in one of the questions I linked above. I think you need to authenticate with username:token using `curl` first, then use the git clone link format discussed in the two issues. That *should* do it.

Comment: I'd also recommend trying `pipenv install -e "git://user:token@github.com/user/repo#egg=package"`

Comment: If I use this:

echo "machine github.com login ei-grad password mypasswordshouldbehere" > ~/.netrc
pip install "git+https://github.com/ei-grad/my_private_repo.git#egg=my_private_repo"

terminal launch a promt in order to open github and do login, and I need put this in a docker contsainer so I think that this cannot be a solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it only worked putting the package in the pipenv file and installing.