# "Proper" way to push to github from command line with an access token

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, command-line-interface, token

Based on the changes to [Github authetication starting yesterday](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/), I am wondering
what the "correct" way to push with access tokens is.

On Ubuntu 20 there isn't any macOS keychain like feature for
managing tokens (that I know of).

Based on this post,
[Authenticate with GitHub using a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token),
many reponses suggest using `git remote set-url https://username:$TOKEN@github.com/$ORG/$REPO`, but doing this seems to store the token's value in plain text in `.git/`.

What then are the best practices for storing access tokens locally? Environment variables?

[Note by torek before closing: in this case the solution was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775982/1256452).]

Comment: (1) Might depend what operating system you're using. (2) Where's the programming in this question?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Shouldn't that fact be in the question?

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu (or any other Linux), it's probably better to drop https and use ssh instead, if possible.

Comment: See one of the many answers already given. For example start at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal-access-to

Comment: found a good fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775982/11015015