# github not accepting token

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push an existing repo to a new GitHub repo.

To do so, I had to generate a token, which I did, and which I copied onto my clipboard.

My understanding is that when I want to push to this new repo, I need to paste the token where I used to type my password. However, this still generates the `remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.` error. What am I not understanding here?

Here is what my terminal window displays:

```
$ git push -u origin main
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/me/expt_results.git/'
```

even though I entered my username into the pop-up window and have tried (numerous times) both pasting the token and hand copying the token in lieu of my password.

I have also tried doing the following:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://[TOKEN]@github.com/[USER]/[REPO]
git push origin main
```

as suggested in [Authenticate with GitHub using a token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token), but with a similar lack of success, though a different error message.

```
$ git push origin main
remote: Permission to [USER]/[REPO] denied to [USER].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/[USER]/[REPO]/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: [TOKEN] => [ID:TOKEN]. 
Have you tested this? Or did you enter only the url without the token?

Comment: It's not a good idea to put the token in the URL.  What scopes did you specify for the token?

Answer (score 1):

you have to `Select the scopes, or permissions`, you'd like to grant this `token`. **To use your token to access repositories from the command line, select repo.** like this

https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/settings/token_scopes.gif