# Authentication error while pushing file on github

Tags: git, github, token, git-push

[Authentication Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhrZa.jpg)

Any one knows how to solve authentication error while pushing file,I tried to generate token but again failed several times.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't know what to do with the unexpected string you gave it. Please make a copy of your local repository (always good to have backups in these cases) and then run the following commands:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://<GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>.git

git push
# Or in your case:    
git push java master
```

Where you have to exchange <GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>, <GITHUB_USERNAME>, and <REPOSITORY_NAME> with the relevant values.

According to [techglimpse](https://techglimpse.com/git-push-github-token-based-passwordless/) this can also be done with the following line:

```
git push https://<GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>.git
```

Other solutions might be found in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token).

Comment: I had to follow exactly the operations described to be able to connect again.