# SSH agent docker compose macbook private git repository

Tags: git, docker, macos, ssh

I am having the following problem making `npm i` inside my docker container. I have a M1 macbook.

```
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/XXXXX/yyy-yyy.git
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: node:18.18
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    user: "1000:1000"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/:/home/node/app/
      - $PWD/.cache/npm:/root/.npm
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "9092:80"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      GIT_SSH_COMMAND: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /ssh-agent
      DEBUG: 1
      GITHUB_TOKEN: $GITHUB_TOKEN
    command: npm run watch
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 256M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 128M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

and package.json

```
    "package-name": "github:XXXXX/package-name#v0.0.3",
```

I also have a .npmrc

```
engine-strict=true
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_TOKEN}
@XXXXX:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

I can provide more information if needed. I know the github token is valid I've used in an ubuntu.

I've tried

```
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock
```

on docker-compose and it doesn't work either.

Output of `ssh -T git@github.com` inside the container:

```
node@d4184eab93b1:~/app$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: The github token isn't used since you're connecting to github through SSH. Either add your public key into github https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account or use https to connect to github https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-a-token

Comment: I've add my ssh key to github. Doesn't work.

Comment: Do you still get `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`? What is the output of `ssh -T git@github.com`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container/66648529#66648529

Comment: I've updated the question with the output. I think the ssh key is not being copied to the container.

Comment: I'm not clear what benefit you're getting from Docker here: you're running an unmodified `node` image, and then trying to inject host code and interact with host resources like the ssh-agent, but conversely you don't seem to be building a reusable image or interacting with any other containers.  Would it be easier to run Node directly on the host system and take Docker out of this setup?

Comment: I have multiple applications and I don't want to run them on my host. I need to keep this setup, I just would like to understand what's the problem with ssh... This setup is working in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try this procedure :

Install socat both on MacOS and in docker container.

```
# On MacOS: find MacOS IP by ifconfig, for ex. 192.168.119.129, then run
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:2222,reuseaddr,fork,bind=192.168.119.129 UNIX-CLIENT:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

```
# In docker container :
$ socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/agentBridge.sock,reuseaddr,fork TCP:192.168.119.129:2222
# From another terminal in container, following two commands should work :
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/run/agentBridge.sock ssh-add -l
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/run/agentBridge.sock ssh -T git@github.com
```

Once above procedure works, you can integrate it in docker-compose workflow.